# Can an NS Record Point To Multiple A Records?

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, dns-hosting

Quick question.  Can an NS record point to multiple A records?

For example, lets say I have a zone subdomain.example.com and an NS record for it pointing to nsmatrix.example.com.

Could I then have multiple A records for nsmatrix.example.com?  Or does it strictly need to be a one-to-one relationship requiring me to setup multiple ns records for the zone.

I'm trying to avoid having extra dns entries if I don't need them.

Thanks,

M

Comment: In case anyone stumbles across this one day, I found this in RFC1034: > The strategy is
to cycle around all of the addresses for all of the servers with a
timeout between each transmission.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to have an `NS` record point at a hostname that itself then has multiple `A` records.

I was looking into this last week and could find nothing in the core DNS-related RFCs that says anything specific about this case.

However it is generally supported by the EPP interface that most domain name registries use.  There are also ICANN documents which describe how they test gTLD nameservers when in this configuration.

That said, I've never seen such a configuration "in the wild".