# Difference between multiple NS and NS having multiple A

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver

I found this [Can an NS Record Point To Multiple A Records?](https://serverfault.com/questions/117499/can-an-ns-record-point-to-multiple-a-records), but wonders what is the difference, if any.

For example:

```
mydomain.com. IN NS ns1.myhost.com.
mydomain.com. IN NS ns2.myhost.com.

ns1.myhost.com. IN A 111.222.333.1
ns2.myhost.com. IN A 111.222.333.2
```

versus

```
mydomain.com. IN NS ns.myhost.com.

ns.myhost.com. IN A 111.222.333.1
ns.myhost.com. IN A 111.222.333.2
```

EDIT: actually, come to think of it, it could be said the same for MX records. Any breaking differences?

EDIT 2: then again, MX allow use of priority values so its a different case, in that one-ip-per-domain is more useful sometimes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a semantic difference.

If an `NS` record (or `MX` record) points to a host name which subsequently resolves to multiple `A` (or `AAAA`) records these are supposed to represent alternate addresses for *the same host* (aka "multihoming").

See paragraphs 8 and 9 in [s5.1 of RFC 5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-5.1).

Hence it's not always required that a client would try every known address for a particular *host*, but it *should* try *every named host*.

So, in the (normal) single-homed case with multiple name servers or mail servers, you should use a different name for each server, with a single IP, rather than one name with multiple IPs.

Comment: just found - take a look http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1034 section 5.3.3 step 3.

Comment: As `Sandman4` points out, it doesn't have the effect that you state, because resolving proxy DNS servers _do_ in fact simply try every IP address returned.  It's actually simpler to implement that way.  Picking and choosing amongst `A` resource records, rather than simply using them all, is _more_ work for an implementor.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose it just can be implementation specific - maybe some odd servers will always use only one of addresses or something like that. But normally probably should be no difference.

Btw, I found one RFC that mentions similar situation - look at [RFC  2181 section 4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2182#section-4).3, 3-rd paragraph. It says one A for one NS, but provide no reasoning.

Edit: The main difference obviously is that (1) is what everybody uses and as such 100% tested, while (2) is what nobody uses and as such there's higher possibility of it being broken is some implementations.

Comment: RFC 2181 §4.3 says "`A` records", plural.  It doesn't say one `A` resource record per `NS` resource record.  It says one `NS` resource record per distinct group of host-local/site-local/global addresses, according to connectivity, with the `A` resource records in the group associated with the intermediate domain name in the value of that `NS` resource record.  Given the split-horizon capabilities of most content DNS server softwares, the multiple `NS` resource records and intermediate domain names aren't really needed in practice.

Answer (score -4):

Read books!

In case of multiple A Records per name resolver will return always **one IP per request** for NS (round-robin'ed from pool), in case of multiple NS Records **all records** will be returned and if one of NS failed, all others will continue to work and serve requests

Comment: no, the name server will quite happily return multiple IP addresses even in the first case.

Comment: @Alnitak - **show** it, not just say

Comment: @LazyBadger dig google.com

Comment: @Alex Don't tell **me** about dig!!! Show real session for multihomed host, where first IP failed, with auto-rollback!!! And apply this to multihomed NS (homework **for you**)

Comment: @LazyBadger you first - you need to show an example that you're right.

Comment: @LazyBadger e.g. `dig an. ns` will give _two_ `A` records for `ns0.ja.net` in the additional section.

Comment: @LazyBadger oh, and then look at my profile and the top user stats on the DNS tag...